# My lightning node URI is not visible

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning

I did set up a mainnet c-lightning node by following the guide.
https://medium.com/@dougvk/run-your-own-mainnet-lightning-node-2d2eab628a8b

I noticed my node is visible on https://lnmainnet.gaben.win/ but the URI is unknown. Is there some settings I need to check on my server?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a specific piece of software and is best asked on that software's developer mailing list.

Comment: @Alin: no, I think OP is about lightning network, which is integral part of bitcoin network.

Answer (score 3):

when starting `lightningd`, you want to add the option:

`--addr=[insert your IP address here]`

so maybe when starting your lightning node, at your command line you would enter:

`lightningd --alias DavideRivola --network bitcoin --log-level debug --port 9735 -ipaddr 192.168.1.1`

Where `192.168.1.1` you would of course, put your own IP address.

Also, since you are probably unaware of this as well, in case you want to choose the port, use the `--port=9735` option and just change the port to which you want to use. Everybody pretty much uses port `9735` though. Make sure that this port is forwarded on your internet router and is not blocked by your firewall either.

Also, if you want to choose the color that represents your LN Node on the #recksplorer site, you can use the following option `--rgb 00cc00` where `00cc00` is the RGB code you would like to use. (In this case I have chosen green, because, well..look at my name :) )

Use this site to find the corresponding RGB Code for the color you want to use: http://www.color-hex.com/

use the command `lightning-cli listconfigs` to check what you have configured for your node to make sure everything is right after it is up and running.